# when should callback functions in JavaScript be used

Tags: node.js

can someone explain me how should we know that when we should use a callback?
like in the code given here as a link
[snip of code is given here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rF8j.png)
we see that in `readFile` method inside `fetchAll(cb)`, we used `callback` denoted by `(cb)` to read the content, `parse` it and `stringify` it and whatever, but in `readFile` method of `save()`, there was no need to use `(cb)`. So how can we know when to use the callback?

Comment: All relevant code need to be posted here directly as text. And you use a callback when you have code to run after since action, and you aren't sure when the action will complete.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. just be aware what is the nature of the methods you are using.
readFile is **async** so it will need a callback. What it is basically saying is "hey, I am going to read the file you asked, but while I read it you can do other stuff instead of waiting for me and when I am finished, I will come back to you". In your readFile method in save() you still pass a callback:

```
(err, fileContent) => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Callback are used to handle **async** code so we can continue work, while something else is happening and we do not want to stop and wait for it.

Comment: but in my readFIle method in fetchAll() also i passed callback like (err, fileContent) so why i used there cb ? what was its need? cant it be done without cb as it is done inside save()?

Comment: Post all relevant code, posting an image as external source is a bad practice. Post the code where you call fetchAll, because you are passing a function whwn you call it and I cannot see any of that in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs=require('fs')
const path=require('path')
module.exports=class Prroduct{
constructor(title,imgurl,description,price){
this.title=title
this.imgurl=imgurl
this.description=description
this.price=price
}
save(){
const p=path.join(__dirname,'../','data','products.json')
fs.readFile(p,(err,fileContent)=>{
let products=[]
if(!err){
products=JSON.parse(fileContent)
}   
products.push(this)
fs.writeFile(p,JSON.stringify(products),(err)=>{
console.log(err)
})
}) 
}
static fetchAll(cb){
const p=path.join(__dirname,'../','data','products.json')
fs.readFile(p,(err,fileContent)=>{
if(err){
         cb([])
     }
    cb(JSON.parse(fileContent))
})
}
}
```